# What does this `*` symbol in this ruby snippet mean? (splat?)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm new to Ruby and trying to read through some code.  I can't figure out what exactly the `*` symbol is telling the Ruby interpreter to do in this snippet:

```
[1]> items = [:one, :two, :three]
=> [:one, :two, :three]
[2]> x = Hash[*items.map { |item| [item, item.to_s+' !!'] }.flatten ]
=> {:one=>"one !!", :two=>"two !!", :three=>"three !!"}
```

Comment: It flattens the data structure if i recall correctly. As in at the source code level, it's like `xargs` in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I had some method in Ruby:

```
def a_method(a,b,c)
  "#{a} #{b} #{c}"
end
```

and an array:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

I want to pass the 3 elements of the array into the method. This will produce an error:

```
a_method(arr) # wrong number of arguments
```

So what do I do? I could certainly do:

```
a_method(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
```

but there's an easier way, using the * "splat" operator:

```
a_method(*arr)
```

Basically, you'll achieve the same effect as above. Think of it like a "shortcut" that "converts" each array element into a method argument when being used when you call a method. This splat operator is a bit complicated to understand because it behaves differently when being used in different places (you have [lots of useful articles](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html) on the topic).

In your example, basically, after the following expression is done:

```
items.map { |item| [item, item.to_s+' !!'] }.flatten
```

it produces:

```
[:one, "one !!", :two, "two !!", :three, "three !!"]
```

and this data is being passed to the `Hash` method using the "splat" operator, because `Hash` will not accept a single array as an argument:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
p Hash{arr} #=> error, wrong number of arguments
p Hash[*arr] #=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d"}
```

Comment: great answer.  so perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `*`, you get

```
Hash[[:one, "one !!", :two, "two !!", :three, "three !!"]]
```

which won't work.  The `*` "splats" the array into a sequence of arguments, giving you:

```
Hash[:one, "one !!", :two, "two !!", :three, "three !!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` in this context is the ["splat" operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

It's function is to turn an array into individual arguments to a function.

Given a function that accepts arguments...

```
def my_func(a, b, c)
end
```

You can invoke this function with three arguments by directly specifying arguments: `my_func(1,2,3)`

Or, if you have an array containing the arguments for the function, you can use the splat operator to "expand" the array to fill the arguments for the function:

```
args = [1,2,3]
my_func(*args) # identical to my_func(1,2,3)
```

In your particular case, there is a class method on Hash called `[]`, which accepts a variable number of arguments. The code is using `map` to produce an array, and then passing each element of the array as an argument to `Hash[]`.